# Whitespace is collapsed with echo >>

Tags: bash

I am creating a script that reads the contents of a file, manipulates the contents and appends to another file (specifically the virtual hosts file). The formatting and whitespace in the output file is important but when I write the contents, the whitespace is stripped out.

```
VHOST_PATH="/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf"
TEMPLATE_PATH="./template.conf"
TEMPLATE=$(<TEMPLATE_PATH)
# manipulating $TEMPLATE
echo $TEMPLATE                   #outputs correct whitespace
echo $TEMPLATE >> $VHOST_PATH    #does not output correct whitespace
```

So the first echo produces something like

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain
    DocumentRoot "root/web"
    ServerName domain
    ErrorLog "root/logs/error_log"
</VirtualHost>
```

but the string that gets into the file is

```
<VirtualHost *:80> ServerAdmin webmaster@domain DocumentRoot "root/web" ServerName domain ErrorLog "root/logs/error_log" </VirtualHost>
```

How do I preserve the whitespace while appending into the target file? I've searched for this but all the similar questions dont apply to my script without rewriting it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like every other program, echo interprets strings separated by whitespace as different arguments.

After calling

```
echo foo    bar
```

the only data that gets passed to echo by the shell is that the first argument is `foo` and the second is `bar`.

To pass a whole string containing whitespaces as a single argument, enclose it in double quotes:

```
echo "foo    bar"
```

will print all four spaces.

Comment: On a side note:  I find it surprising that `echo $TEMPLATE` would work. It should collapse multiple whitespaces as well.

Comment: Yes! That was it. It makes complete sense but I didnt realize this was the case. Also, `echo $TEMPLATE` was working because I had quotes around it but I neglected to copy it over to my post.I didnt think that was important. I was wrong!

Comment: @Jeff See the following: [Commands and Arguments](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/CommandsAndArguments)

Comment: @Jeff, it's critically important, when seeking assistance, to cut and paste instead of re-typing.

Comment: @glennjackman i thought i could get away with retyping since the scripts were so short and copy+paste would be a pain since i was working in a terminal. i was wrong. lesson learned. thanks for the tip.

Comment: But if we assign the quoted echo value to a variable and then again echo that output it will remove the space 
Like :   abc=`echo "spaces       not   maintained      properly"`
echo $abc

Comment: @Jagdeep: Try `echo "$abc"`.

Comment: @Dennis: Thanks Dennis for replying,  i also got the idea after typing my query.
it has worked . Thanks anyway